# iOS Streaming background audio

Tags: ios, stream, streaming, avaudioplayer

The following is the code that works just find to get the audio to stream:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    connectionPlay = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSError *playerError;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:streamData error:&playerError];
    player.numberOfLoops = 0;
    player.volume = 1.0f;
    [player prepareToPlay];

    if (playerError) {
        NSLog(@"audio player error: %@", [playerError localizedDescription]);
    }
    if (player == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@", [playerError description]);
    else
        [player play];
```

When I attempt to take the app into background mode, i seizes to play. I have gone into the .plist and have entered Required background modes, item 0, App plays Audio. This did not fix my problem.

I began placing this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                       error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES
                                     error:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Inside of

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

and

inside of the viewDidLoad in the main ViewController. As well as right after [player prepareToPlay].

I am not sure if the issue is with me not setting the proper background settings or with the app cutting out the connection. Basically, I am not sure what I am missing.

I have been looking at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html

EDIT: anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what it was, but I just transferred all of code to a new project, added this code

```
 - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                           error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES
                                         error:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}
```

and the plist settings, and it seems to work on the phone, but not the simulator..